# How to fix missing scope error in Slack (rtm.connect) API?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

When I try to use the `rtm.connect` method with own token, tester returns me a false response.

URL : `https://slack.com/api/rtm.connect?token=xoxp-532016xxxxx-53xxxxxx-536743xxxxxx-9211bedc4bfe9ddfexxxxxxxxxxxxxx&pretty=1`

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "missing_scope",
    "needed": "rtm:stream",
    "provided": "identify,incoming-webhook,channels:history,im:history,channels:read,im:read,team:read,users:read,users:read.email,users.profile:read,chat:write:user,files:write:user"
}
```

What am I missing in request? Why does this `missing_scope` error occur? I already followed the Slack documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to first create user bot. Follow this [link](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) and create one.

Then you will get **Bot User OAuth Access Token** under **Install App** in left Navigation bar.

Use this **Bot User OAuth Access Token** for above request.