# Assigned scope permission is not recognized in Slack API request

Tags: slack-api

I am facing the same issue as this question

[Slack API Opening a New DM (Scopes and Permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235774/slack-api-opening-a-new-dm-scopes-and-permissions)

I have these permissions assigned
[image]

```
   ok error         needed   provided
   -- -----         ------   --------
 False missing_scope im:write identify,channels:read,users:read
```

The self-answer in the other question implies that I need to use the bot token, instead. I don't think I have a bot token (and am not the application administrator so I can't get in), but it seems like I should be able to submit this with the user token as well.

Comment: you are correct. this would work with the access token too. But your token apparently is missing the `im:write` scope. did you re-install your app to the workspace after adding the scope?

Comment: Reinstalling the app was the answer. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scopes are added a Slack app has to be re-installed into the workspace (using the [OAuth 2.0 process](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth)) to activate those changes.